# this returns different between browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, coffeescript, scope, requirejs

I've stumbled upon an issue I can't get my head around, and I hope some smart people here might enlighten me :-)

The following CoffeeScript using RequireJs gives me a problem with scope. It Works perfectly with any other browser expect for our old friend Internet Explorer (even in latest version).

Problem being that `this.stop()`, or rather just `this` gives me `window` in Internet Explorer and the object where all the code bellow live in when in other browsers.

So Internet Explorer tries to do `window.stop()`, which obviously won't work. Whilst other browsers just run the `stop()` method in the scope it should. Why is this?

Does it has to do with the Array prototype function `.push()` working in some other way in Internet Explorer? Or is it just a bug? Please enlighten me?

```
define ['require', 'cs!scroller', 'cs!router', 'jquery', 'cs!menu', 'cs!magicbox', 'newsflash', 'swiper', 'time', 'cs!ads'], (require, Scroller, Router, $, Menu, Magicbox, Newsflash, Swiper, Time) ->

  start: ->

    Router.addRouterEvents()

    window.Looper = []

    window.Looper.push () ->
      [this.stop(), Router.start(), Scroller.start(), Newsflash(), Swiper(), Time()]

    for func in window.Looper
      func()

  stop: ->
    $('*').off()
```

Here is the same code compiled to JavaScript (for the less CoffeeScript versed among us, since I do not except the problem lies with CoffeeScript itself):

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
(function() {
  define(['require', 'cs!scroller', 'cs!router', 'jquery', 'cs!menu', 'cs!magicbox', 'newsflash', 'swiper', 'time', 'cs!ads'], function(require, Scroller, Router, $, Menu, Magicbox, Newsflash, Swiper, Time) {
    return {
      start: function() {
        var func, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
        Router.addRouterEvents();
        window.Looper = [];
        window.Looper.push(function() {
          return [this.stop(), Router.start(), Scroller.start(), Newsflash(), Swiper(), Time()];
        });
        _ref = window.Looper;
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
          func = _ref[_i];
          _results.push(func());
        }
        return _results;
      },
      stop: function() {
        return $('*').off();
      }
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Is it possible it works in chrome because chrome was using a cached version. I ran into this a couple of times when loading JavaScript with JavaScript and ended up installing a no cache extension to take care of it

Comment: I have disabled cache. So that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not run *your* code, but I'm betting that you actually have the *same* basic problem on all platform. When the functions you push on your `Looper` array are executed, they always get `window` as the value of `this`.

The thing is that `window` has a `stop` method on multiple platforms but not on IE. ([This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.stop) is my source for saying this.) So when you are running on IE, you get an error right away. On other platforms you get to call `window.stop()`, which is not what you want. For kicks, I ran this in Chrome, no errors:

```
(function () { this.stop() })()
```

You can have `this` set to the value you want by using `bind`. It would look like this in JavaScript:

```
window.Looper.push(function() {
    return [this.stop(), Router.start(), Scroller.start(), Newsflash(), Swiper(), Time()];
}.bind(this));
```

(Notice the `.bind(this)` at the end of the anonymous function.)

I would suggest adding `"use strict";` at the beginning of the anonymous function you give to `define`. It makes JavaScript operate under saner semantics than without it, and would have helped finding the problem here because `this` would have been `undefined` instead of set to `window`.

Comment: Thank you! That must be the case. Further investigation tells me nothing in my stop-method actually get executed and what you're saying explains why I get errors only in IE and not other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Th resulting JS struck me as a little odd. It looks like from your CoffeeScript that you're trying to set up window.Looper as an array of functions, which you loop over and call each function as you go? But the JavaScript gives us the insight that in actuality the variable _i is never going to go past 0, since it is looping over the array window.Looper, which contains a single item, which is the function you push into it here:

```
window.Looper.push(function() {
   return [...];
});
```

You then execute this single function here:

```
_results.push(func());
```

and that in turn executes this function:

```
function() {
      return [this.stop(), Router.start(), Scroller.start(), Newsflash(), Swiper(), Time()];
}
```

which returns an array of functions that are executed as they are added to the array. So your loop isn't really achieving anything, in that all you need to do within this setup is forget about the _i loop and instead call:

```
window.Looper[0]()
```

to execute everything in your array of functions.

So this sequence of  function calls looks complex and I can believe you run into scope issues. I'm not entirely sure, but given the this.stop() is being executed as a result of window.Looper0 returning an anonymous function, I would have thought the scope would have been the window for all browsers - I am puzzled as to how this code works at all! EG, here is a cut-down version showing the value of 'this' when you call this.stop() is indeed the window:

http://repl.it/XPF/1

It's possible require/js is doing some magic to make it work that I am failing to simulate in that repl.it snippet. Either way, I think the fix is that JavaScript would benefit from being simplified to simply this:

```
window.Looper = [this.stop, Router.start, Scroller.start, Newsflash, Swiper, Time]
```

ie, an array of function references that you can loop, and call. Here's an example, showing this concept without require.js and a stub for a Router.start:

http://repl.it/XPF

I think the corresponding coffee script would then be:

```
define ['require', 'cs!scroller', 'cs!router', 'jquery', 'cs!menu', 'cs!magicbox', 'newsflash', 'swiper', 'time', 'cs!ads'], (require, Scroller, Router, $, Menu, Magicbox, Newsflash, Swiper, Time) ->

  start: ->

    Router.addRouterEvents()

    // Push funcs into the array, in case there is already something there (see comments)
    // Probably a nicer way of doing this in CoffeeScript
    // in JS I'd do window.Looper.push.apply(window.Looper, [func, func])
    window.Looper.push(this.stop)
    window.Looper.push(Router.start)
    window.Looper.push(Scroller.start)
    window.Looper.push(Newsflash)
    window.Looper.push(Swiper)
    window.Looper.push(Time)

    for func in window.Looper
      func()

  stop: ->
    $('*').off()
```

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. The logic it self isn't flawed, even if I myself also am puzzled by the scope problem and differences. Let me explain and perhaps make sense of the somewhat complex logic going on and explain why i use a function.
As you say, the loop in this case do not make much sense. But window.Looper might already have data in it. And that is why we run it though a loop. Why I push a function into window.Looper is because I do not want it to be executed until the entire loop is run.

Comment: That makes sense, but two further thoughts: (1) you reset window.Looper here `window.Looper = [];` and (2) as I say, your loop isn't really doing anything so your goal of looping over the functions to execute them isn;t happening, except via a convoluted series of function calls! To be sure you don't mess with anything already in window.Looper, you can still use push, but make sure you push in function references, don't push in your complex function-returning-an-array-of-function-calls. I'll modify my example to show you. I really suggest you do give it a try!